# Is there any way to set Date only through ReadLine() to a DateTime type variable? How?

Tags: c#, datetime, console-application

I know i could do this and it works

```
string Dob; //string
Console.WriteLine("Enter date of Birth in format DD/MM/YYYY: ");
Dob = Console.ReadLine();
```

But i want something like this! a predefined method or shorthad way

```
DateTime Dob; //DateTime
Console.WriteLine("Enter date of Birth in format DD/MM/YYYY: ");
//What i am expecting, but is not possible as its DateTime 
Dob = Console.ReadLine(); // expects a string
```

Is there a specific method to get date only into the Dob Variable directly from the Key Board.

Is there a predefined method for this in the DateTime class?
What's the best way or shortest way to achieve this?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`?

Comment: @cubrr it's not working for me, it throws System.FormatException

Comment: Then you're giving it the date in the wrong format.

Comment: @cubrr Last time i checked 20/12/2015 does comply to the dd/MM/yyyy format

Comment: @Black0ut `DateTime.Parse(String)` uses `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo`. See what format `DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo)` is in.

Comment: @cubrr So i guess all we got to do is to hope that aimme date settings are the same as yours :)

Comment: guys thank you for the responses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, this is the easiest and shortest way i found, as [cubrr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/996081/cubrr) commented.

```
DateTime Dob;
Console.WriteLine("Enter date of Birth in format MM/DD/YYYY: ");
//accepts date in MM/dd/yyyy format
Dob = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 9):

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime dt;
while (!DateTime.TryParseExact(line, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid date, please retry");
    line = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This works but in my region Chicago, Illinois the default date style is MM/DD/YYYY. Maybe that is the default with none set as the DateTimeStyles attribute. Did you mean to type mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy. Also, I completely see the illogical nature of our date format, as it **should** go from largest to smallest or the other way around but I got a little confused when debugging this bit of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the string class in .net by writing an extension function as the following.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DateTime? Dob(this string strLine)
    {
        DateTime result;
        if(DateTime.TryParseExact(strLine, "dd/MM/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        else 
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use it on any string object. See the example below to see what I'm talking about.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your date of birth in DD/MM/YYYY:");

        // Option 1.
        // The Console.ReadLine() function returns a string.
        string strDob = Console.ReadLine();
        DateTime? dob1 = strDob.Dob();


        // Option 2.
        // You can combine the two steps together into one line for smoother reading.
        DateTime? dob = Console.ReadLine().Dob();            
    }
}
```

Note: The question mark (?) at the end of the DateTime type converts the DateTime "struct" into a nullable "object". If you set a DateTime "struct" equal to null it will throw an exception where as DateTime? can be set to null. It is good practice to consider using DateTime? (nullable) as opposed to using the DateTime "struct"

Answer (score 1):

This method converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information. The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2009/05/08","yyyy/MM/dd",
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!